# Will BiDirectional JAVA Contract testing work on OAS generated using GoLang code-base?

Tags: pact, pactflow

Will BiDirectional Consumer driven Contract testing work just using OAS file generated using project which is GoLang based?
But no direct access to Codebase.
Is there an example for this

Thanks
Ref:
https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/bi-directional-contract-testing/provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no reason why you can't test an OAS that is generated in this way. There are many ways in which an OAS can be generated across languages, tools etc. however we have several examples from which you can extrapolate here: https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples

Comment: Thanks. So for Provider code-base on Golang, I could have Pact Bidirectional Provider & Consumer tests in JAVA? without needed to have any access to GoCode base. Just OWS file would suffice?

Comment: Yes. You should generate the OAS from the code or at least test (through whatever means that works best for your team) that the OAS is implemented by your Golang code base. Once the OAS is uploaded to PactFlow, it is compared to the tests from your Java code base.

Comment: It is giving error when I tried to publish OAS yaml file as provider `pact_broker-client-1.66.1/lib/pact_broker/client/pact_hash.rb:11:in `consumer_name': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`...full command-> ```pact-broker publish /<my_location>/openapi-json.json --broker-base-url https://<my_url>.pactflow.io \ --broker-token <my_token> --consumer-app-version 1.0.0```

Comment: Please see https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/bi-directional-contract-testing/contracts/oas#publishing-the-provider-contract--results-to-pactflow. The `pact-broker publish` command is for pacts, you want the `pactflow publish-provider-contract` command